# Forming a list of indexes of another list, depending from the input values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Stackoverflow, hello

I have a task to form a list of indexes of variables from initial list depends from the input values:

```
initial_list=['a', 'b', 'c']
desired_index_variable=[str(i) for i in input('Input desired indexes with space between ').split()]
try:
    for element in initial_list:
        final_list=[]
        desired_index=final_list.append(initial_list.index(element))
        print (desired_index)
except ValueError:
    print ('No such element in initial list')
```

Here is my try to form such type of list, but the result is (I don't uderstand why there are three "Nones" either):

```
Input desired indexes with space between a b
None
None
None
```

However, the required result is:

```
 [0, 1]
```

By my new-user logic my program is brilliantly OK, but the Python says that it's not, evidently =(

Comment: `final_list.append` will always return `None`, not an index

Comment: Why are you not using the input (ie desired_index_variable) anywhere, can you explain how the input affects the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

1. Don't initialize `final_list` inside the for loop:

```
    final_list=[]
    desired_index=final_list.append(initial_list.index(element))
```

You are setting `final_list` to an empty list at each iteration.
2. You do not need to set desired_index from final_list. Just directly append.

```
desired_index.append(initial_list.index(element))
```

3. You should loop over the `desired_index_variable`. 
   Fixing all of these issues, the following works for me:

```
initial_list=['a', 'b', 'c']
desired_index_variable=[str(i) for i in input('Input desired indexes with space between ').split()]
try:
    desired_index=[]
    for element in desired_index_variable:
        desired_index.append(initial_list.index(element))
    print (desired_index)
except ValueError:
    print ('No such element in initial list')
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.append` does work *in-place* and returns `None`. Consider following example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a.append(4)
print(a)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(b)  # None
```

If you do not want *in-place* behavior you might do:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a+[4]
print(a)  # [1, 2, 3]
print(b)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I've tried "desired_index=final_list+[initial_list.index(element)]" instead of "desired_index=final_list.append(initial_list.index(element))". The result is "[0] // [1] // [2]", which is also not correct(